# How to create a spherical image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

My setup has checkerboard charts with known world coordinates present in each image that I use to stitch images together (in a 2D plane) and to find my P-matrix. However, I am stuck on finding a general approach into combining all my images into a spherical image.

Known:

- Ground truth correspondence points in each image
- camera calibration parameters (camera matrix, distortion coefficients)
- homography between images
- world-image plane matrix: P = K[R | t] for each image. However I think this matrix's estimation isn't that great.
- real world coordinates of ground truthed points
- camera has almost only rotation, minimal translation
- I know openGL well enough to do the spherical/texture wrapping once I can stitch the images into a cubemap format

Unknown:

- Spherical image
- image cubemap

Comment: for each picture, estimate the camera's rotation/pose in world space. and maybe you'd like an "equirectangular" projection instead of a cubemap. a cubemap from known camera orientations should be doable though.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the pointers! Also, while working on this I've come across the image coordinates (x,y,z). What does the z-coord refer to since normally its normalized to (x/z,y/z,1)? Is it the distance to the image plane i.e. fx or fy if we assume fx=fy?

Comment: I don't understand. show where you see this.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz [Sleziski paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dyer/cs534/papers/szeliski97.pdf) start of page 2, or another [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6413586) bottom of page 3, column 1. (theta,phi) are calculated like this in the 2nd paper theta=arccos(z/sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)), phi=arctan(sqrt(x^2+y^2)/z) but there's no clarification on where an image z-coordinate comes from or if its just 1.

Comment: ah yes. vector (in space) represents sight/light ray (in space) for that pixel (on a plane). you can map from one view to another by composing camera/projection matrices and a rotation matrix (both cams same optical center). H = C R C^-1. inputs are (x,y,1) coordinates of the pixels of the source image. those points/vectors would lie on the image plane. homography transforms them. projective space: all (x,y,1)*w for any w represent the same point (x,y) in "actual" space, and (x,y,1) canonically represents that point in the projective space. involves division. (x,y,z,1)*w representing (x,y,z).